# SELECT without commas between attributes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help understanding the following queries and why they are valid/invalid:

```
SELECT first_name last_name, salary FROM employee    VALID
SELECT first_name, last_name salary FROM employee    VALID
SELECT first_name last_name salary FROM employee     INVALID
```

For reference, the first retrieves last_name and salary and the second retrieves first_name and salary.

Also, to note, the "extra" unprinted column on the valid lines must be an actual row. Typing something like "asfsfasfs last_name, salary" will be INVALID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the second case, salary is considered as an alias for last_name.

So you will get `last_name` value, but named `salary` (the column header in a resultset, for example). So it's valid, but you don't retrieve salary's value.

In the third case, you have too much spaces (an alias can't have spaces if you don't put quotes around it), so it's not valid.